# making the main scroll bars controll a div thats set to overflow:scroll?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

ive got a div that takes up most of my page, its set to overflow scroll but what id like it to do, is have it conrolled not by scroll bars on the div itself but by the main scroll bars on the right hand side of the browser window..

is this possable ? theres no other scrollable divs on the page so it would only be controlling this one..

the main reason i want to do this is is dont want the scroll bars in the middle of my site as some browsers default scroll bars are rather ugly

Answer (score 1):

set

css:

```
div{

overflow:auto;
}
```

js:

```
$("div").height($("div")[0].scrollHeight);
```

Comment: sorry, please ignore that last comment